# Overlay is expanding outside the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, overlay

I have an overlay that is supposed to cover the entire page when opened - it works except all of the sudden the overlay is larger than the viewport by about 50px and causes a horizontal scroll. I am not sure how to ensure that the overlay only covered the viewport size? I was using `width: 100vw` and that worked perfectly and now I can't seem to keep the size inside of the vw of various screen sizes.

```
    .modal-footer-large {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10px 40px;
   }
```

Comment: try adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using cover size

```
background-size:cover;
```

OR:

```
width: 100%
```